# Guice inject cannot be cast to class

Tags: java, proxy, guice

I am seeing the following error when I tried to using proxy to wrap an interface.

```
1) [Guice/ErrorInjectingConstructor]: ClassCastException: class jdk.proxy2.$Proxy111 cannot be cast to class A (jdk.proxy2.$Proxy111 is in module jdk.proxy2 of loader 'app'; A is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
......
```

We have two Modules X and Y, Y is depended on X by the following:

```
protected void configure() {
    ......
    install(new moduleX(config.getModuleXConfig(), config));
    ....
```

Wrapper and handler are defined in Module X:

```
public class MyProxyWrapper {
public static <T> T wrap(T clazz) {
    T proxy = (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            clazz.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            clazz.getClass().getInterfaces(),
            new MyProxyWrapper<>(clazz)
    );
    return proxy;
    }
}


class MyProxyWrapper<T> implements InvocationHandler {
    private final T realObject;

    public MyProxyWrapper(T realObject) {
        this.realObject = realObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        ......
        Object result = method.invoke(realObject, args);
        return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e.getCause();
        }
    }
}
```

The class A is defined in Module X the injection happened in Module Y.

```
@Inject
public UpdateDnsEntriesStep(
......
        SomeClient someClient, 
        AnotherClient anotherClient,
     ) {
    this.dnsUpdateClient = MyProxyWrapper.wrap(dnsUpdateClient); //This line return the error
    this.hopsClient = hopsClient;  // This is the current working version
......
    }
```

In my test the Interface B defined in Module Y will work. However the Interface A defined in Module X does not.
I guess it could by some class load hierarchy issue but not sure what it is.
Does anyone has anyidea? Any help is appreciated.

I tried updated the Cuice to the lattest as I saw this thread mentioned that Guice may not work with the JDK17: https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1536
Also tried define the wrapper in Module Y but get the same error.